# Only one multi-branch scan happens at a given point of time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have quite a few multi branch pipelines in a monorepo and only one multi branch scan happens at a given point of time and the remaining scans that started in parallel halts in the below step and proceeds in a serial fashion.

```
 > git ls-remote --symref -- git@gitlab.xxx.xx.com:xx/xxx.git # timeout=10
```

We are using git branch source plugin and gitlab branch source is taking way too long (like hours, may be because this is a monorepo).

Any tips/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Added more executors to the controller node which didn't help.